# Python: CX-Freeze And Pyrogram - Failed Import Module

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyrogram

I can't turn a simple python code into an executable(with `CX-Freeze`) when I use the Pyrogram library (Error (print) at the end of the post).

I actually shortened the `app.py` code to just print something, and I noticed that I'm doing something wrong when trying to build the code.

What am I doing wrong? I believe it's in Pyrogram's Client class, but you can't include it, as it's not a module.

app.py:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import filters

print("Hello World")
```

setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "includes": ["pyrogram"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for
# a console application).

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name="App",
    version="1.0",
    description="App description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=[Executable("app.py", base=base)]
)
```

**Error**

I believe that the error will occur due to the lack of inclusion of `pyrogram.Client` - but it is not possible to include, because it is not a module, but a class.

I don't know what else to do, so I ask for help who understands the subject better, help to do it. I'll leave the print of the error below:

[image]

Comment: error doesn't show problem with `pyrogram.Class` but with `ConfigSimple`. It can be some extra module which you may have to manually add to setup.

Comment: @furas Yeah, actually I meant "Pyrogram.Client", but in setup.py, when I include 'pyrogram' as is, it should include everything.. At least I could say 'pyrogram.*' or something like that, but I don't believe it works. Only reference I have about ConfigSimple is this: https://docs.pyrogram.org/telegram/base/help/config-simple